# I want to perform a click event on a div that is present in response of ajax query

Tags: php, ajax

I have a home.php page, which has the following code.

```
<div class="container" id="content">
    </div>
```

ajaxpage.php has the following code

```
<div class='thumbnail'></div>
```

Now when from my home page on some click event ajax query goes to the ajaxpage.php
and the response is rendered fine on the home.php page. 
i.e,

```
<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class='thumbnail'></div>
</div>
```

Now again i want to perform a click event to get an alert on a div having class='thumbnail'.
But when i'm doing this i'm not getting the alert nor any error. 
Please help, as i'm stuck in this code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you attaching the click event to the element?  I don't see any JavaScript code here.  The `div` you added to the page is no different from any other `div`.  Once it's added you can attach a click event handler to it like any other.

Comment: Should we guess your code?

Comment: Where is your code for click event ??

Comment: Depending on the version of jquery that you're using, you can either use `live` or delegates

Comment: @asprin, live is deprecated. Use `on`

Comment: @asprin I wouldn't assume he's using JQuery. His question doesn't mention a framework

Comment: @turson That's why I said `Depending on the version`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, the following would do the trick for you:

## < v1.7 ([live](http://api.jquery.com/live/))

```
$('div.thumbnails').live('click', function(){
    alert('Dynamic element');
});
```

## > v1.7 ([on](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

```
$('div.container').on('click', 'div.thumbnails', function(){
    alert('Dynamic element');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '#content .thumbnail', function(){
        alert(1);
    });
});
```

Tell me if it's ok. Don't use live, is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Romeo Onisim. It worked. Before your comment i was using onclick/live to get the desired output for my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event of jQuery

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('.thumbnail').on("click",function()
    {

       alert(1);

    });


});
```

**To dynamically generated elements (for example coming from an AJAX call), you might want to have the same click handler that was previously bound to the same element selector, you then "delegate" the click event using on() with selector argument**

**As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().
This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers when content is dynamically added to a page. See the discussion of direct versus delegated events in the .on() method for more information.**